# Effect of variable permittivity

Tags: electromagnetism, coulombs-law

If I immerse a rod vertically in a liquid with a relative permittivity gradient (the permittivity decreases with depth), will the rod stretch (will the spacing of the atoms in the rod be affected by the varying permittivity)?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you think it should? I see no reason for the rod to strech at all.

Comment: According to Coulomb's law, the force between 2 charged particles is inversely proportional to permittivity.  I was wondering if that means that there would be a gradient of electrical forces inside the rod and what effect (if any) that might have on the dimensions of the rod.

Comment: But the permittivity in the space between the atoms does not change - the liquid does not penetrate the rod on a molecular level, does it?

Comment: That's a good point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Permittivity is a macroscopic property of matter - it is a consequence of the way material is polarized in the presence of an electric field.

The properties of an atomic bond are determined by the atoms participating in the bond, the molecular structure in which they find themselves, and (to a lesser extent) the presence of a magnetic and / or electric field that is strong enough to affect the energy states of the orbitals.

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking about the influence of material outside of a (macroscopic) rod on the inter-atomic bonds. I believe that if there were any effect at all, it would be impossibly hard to measure.

Immersing a polymer (especially nylon) in a liquid can cause significant dimensional changes due to the absorption of water. But permittivity - no, it will not affect the rod.

Answer (score 0):

On a microscopic level the effect you describe does occur.  For example, the force between two molecular ions or polar molecules will be affected by the presence of water molecules in the space between them.

As ACurious points out, there will be little or no effect if the liquid is on the outside of the rod.